# How to access "Up" button in onPrepareOptionsMenu and toggle its visibility at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I want to toggle the visibility of the "Up" button (the left arrow) on `ActionBar` at runtime. I tried to access the button in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` using the item id `R.id.home` since this id works in `onOptionsItemSelected`, however I keep getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for that particular line in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` on activity's creation. What is the correct item id for the "Up" button? Or is there a better way to toggle the "Up" button **at runtime**?

Here is my code:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem up = menu.getItem(R.id.home);
    if (phase != Phase.IDLE) {  // this is the runtime situation in which I want to disable the Up navigation
        up.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        up.setVisible(true);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have also tried `android.R.id.home`, got the same error.

Comment: `android.R.id.home` ?

Comment: @Wizard I tried that, same error :(

Comment: `getItem()` takes an index value, which is why you get that particular Exception. `findItem()` takes an ID, but, even if there is a `View` with ID `android.R.id.home` in your `Activity`, it's not an item in the options menu. You would get it with a regular `findViewById()` call. There very well may not be a home button with that ID, though, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution through Android documentation and thought it would be better to post it back here. Although none of the other answers fully worked in toggling the Up button (at least not on the platform I was working with), some of them (and the comments) were quite helpful, especially in pointing me to using `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`. However, the key here is a call to **`invalidateOptionsMenu()`** that forces the menu to be redrawn.

To quote the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu):

> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
>   open when menu items are presented in the app bar. When an event
>   occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
>   invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu().

So my final solution is:

- Store the `ActionBar` as an instance variable (thanks to @rupinderjeet);
- Call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` on the `ActionBar` whenever I want to toggle the Up button;
- **Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` immediately after each call to `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`.**

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to toggle the "Up" button at runtime?

declare variable globally,

```
private ActionBar supportActionBar;
```

In `onCreate()`,

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  // v7.Toolbar from support package
supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

In your desired method,

```
if (supportActionBar != null) {
    supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // or false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using the default toolbar**

```
    //show
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //hide
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

**if you are using a custom toolbar .**

```
    // get a refrence to your toolbar 
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default Action bar, the get the action bar and setDisplayHomeAsEnabled(true).

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null)

        {
            //setting action bar with custom color defined in colors
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new 
            ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.action_bar)));
            actionBar.setTitle("ActionBar Name");
        }
```

and for setting any action for the back arrow press ,

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            // home (back arrow) icon id
            // do Task here

         }
```